# Can I pass two roles to the function get_users?

Tags: functions, users

I want to get the users of role academic and student.  I have tried using the code below (passing an array of roles, but all users are being displayed, so clearly it's not working.

```
$roles=array('academic','student');
$args =array('role'=>$roles);
$users=get_users( $args );

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it with the get_users function. From what the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) implies, you cannot pass arrays to the role argument. But it should be fairly easy to code your way out of that limitation.

Try this:

```
function filter_two_roles($user) {
    $roles = array('academic','student');
    return in_array($user->roles[0], $roles);
}

$users = get_users('fields=all_with_meta');
// Sort by last name
usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'if($a->last_name == $b->last_name) { return 0;} return ($a->last_name > $b->last_name) ? 1 : -1;'));
// Iterate through users, filtering out the ones which don't have the roles we want 
foreach(array_filter($users, 'filter_two_roles') as $user) {
    // Your code
}
```

Asking for users with the argument field=all_with_meta is very powerful, and WP seems to map indexes which aren't even shown when doing a print_r on the user object. That is why we can sort them using first or last names, as shown above (I actually took the code from [an older answer of mine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29179/order-by-first-name/44222#44222)).

Let us know how it goes?

Comment: thanks for this.  Where do I put my two user role types though?

Comment: I may not be able to use the get_users function anyway because I need to sort the output by last name, and I have realised that object that get_users returns doesn't have a parameter of last name :( so I can't say orderby=last_name

Comment: 1) The roles from the question are already in the code (line 2). You can edit the 'filter_two_roles' function to get other roles too. 2) You most certainly can sort them by first or last name; I've edited the answer to provide this as well.

Comment: Wow thank you SO much, that works perfectly.  I really am so grateful, I spent about 2 hours at work this afternoon trying to get round this, seen this answer when I got home and couldn't resist trying it.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked :)

Comment: hey, sorry to bug you again but would you know how I would be able to only get those users that are 'approved'?  By that I mean I have a plugin that only lets approved members log in.  I don't want these members adding to my directory.  So, delving into the plugin I find the code `if ($user_data->pw_user_status != 'approved')` - can this be built into the above function somehow?  P.S `$user_data = get_user_by( 'login', trim( $username ) )`

Comment: hey its ok, I realised that i could just wrap a massive `if(!empty($firstname))` round the echoed out bit, much easier.

Answer (score 1):

loop through the roles and merge the results...
this will work with any number of roles.

```
$roles = array('academic','student');
$users = array();
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $args = array('role'=>$role);
    $usersofrole = get_users($args);
    $users = array_merge($usersofrole,$users);
}

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
}
```