# Ordering users of a specific role by last name

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

I'm trying to display a list of authors by their last name. I can get the list to display but as yet I don't seem to be able to order the list by last name. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Josh

```
<?php
    $args  = array(
    // search only for Authors role
    // order results by display_name
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key ' => 'last_name',
    'role' => 'guest-teacher'



    // check for two meta_values
    );
    // Create the WP_User_Query object
    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    // Get the results
    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
    // Check for results
    if (!empty($authors))
    {
        echo '<ul class="permanent">';
        // loop trough each author
        foreach ($authors as $author)
        {
            // get all the user's data
            $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
            $url = get_author_posts_url($author->ID);  

    ?>


        <h3><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $author_info->last_name; ?>         </a></h3>

            <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently an open ticket about this [bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21581).

Here is a workaround that I tested:

```
$args  = array(
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'role'     => 'guest-teacher'
);

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'wp_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );
$wp_user_query->query();

$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
```

Problem with this is that it runs the query twice.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I get no results with your code. When I remove the second query I get the same results in order of ID.

Comment: That is weird, I just tested and it works for me. Mind that I edited the answer with an adjustment. Try again, and also tell me what happens if you `var_dump($authors)`;

Comment: I get a NULL back.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($wp_user_query->query_orderby)` both before changing it and after?

Comment: Before I get `string(23) "ORDER BY user_login ASC"` After I get `string(35) "ORDER BY wp_usermeta.meta_value ASC"`

Comment: Do you use a different table prefix for Wordpress than `wp_`? What is the result of `var_dump($wp_user_query->query_where)`?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I changed the wp_usermeta.meta_value to my prefix and it is sorted. I can't thank you enough. Really helped me out of a hole!

Comment: Just noting for newcommers that the orderby issue mentioned has been fixed since WordPress 3.7 and documentation for using 'orderby' => 'meta_value' can be found here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 3):

The following works on my install:

```
$args  = array(
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'meta_key'  => 'last_name',
        'role'      => 'subscriber'
    );
```

So did you try:

```
$args  = array(
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'meta_key'  => 'last_name',
        'role'      => 'guest-teacher'
    );
```

and change the `order` parameter to `DESC` or `ASC` to check if it has any effect?

ps: And do you have the *lastname* filled out for these users?

Comment: thanks, but it is having no effect regardless of what I put in the meta_key parameter. It seems to keep displaying in order of user ID.

Comment: ahh, same thing happening to me, by change the ids are in the same order as lastname ;-) Will check if I can order by lastname.

Comment: This should be the best answer !

Comment: @Warface thanks, glad to hear it worked out for you.