# Create Next and Previous Link to User orderby Last Name

Tags: users, author, author-template

Within author.php, I have a left and right arrow that is supposed to move to the NEXT or PREVIOUS user orderby based on **last_name**.

So if I had users with these names:

1. Julie Brown
2. Jane Cook
3. John Doe
4. Jack Eagle
5. Jason Fox

So if I'm looking at John Doe's ***author.php***, the next button would automatically link to ***Jack Eagle*** for example. And the previous button would automatically link to ***Jane Cook***. THis would be alphabetical based on lastname.

Does anyone know how I can code the left and right arrows to do that.

I'm trying to display a list of authors by their last name. I can get the list to display but as yet I don't seem to be able to order the list by last name. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Josh

I found a thread that orders users by last_name, but I don't know how to use it within author.php to create a Next / Previous button to correctly go to the next user ordered by last_name.

Thread I found has part of the answer: [Ordering users of a specific role by last name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/ordering-users-of-a-specific-role-by-last-name)